# about .dSYM and GDB

Tags: ios, ipad, gdb, crash-reports

I encountered a crash in my app. It's not 100% reproduce rate crash. From the crash log and dSYM, I can get the point where the crash happened in the line of some cpp file. But most of time the app run well. So I don't know what cause it crash. Can I got more infos in the line of cpp where it crash,like some value of varible in this line when the app crash and so on. Any suggestion is welcomed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your crash log should have information about the state of the registers in it and that can be quite useful.  Beyond that, though, you can't recover state of the running app from just the crash report.

Comment: Can the crash log work like dump in PC? The dump can work like a break point, it stop at where the program crash and I can easily to watch all infos in the callstack.

Comment: A crash log is not a core dump;   none of the state of memory is known.  The only thing you can do is run the app in the debugger, set a breakpoint on the line mentioned in the crash log and try to reproduce the crashing state or otherwise inspect the state at the crash point to try and figure out why a crash might occur.

Answer (score 0):

Sporadic bugs such as this can be the most difficult to hunt down.

First of all I suggest taking a close look at the code? e.g. Is there a de-referencing of a pointer on this line. Does your crash log indicate that the error occurred before or after the tread returned to the run loop? Can you surround this crash line with an exception and log the state in the catch block?

It will help if you post the code which causes the crash!